# "expected identifier or '('" in a for loop

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to compile this code

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = get_int("How many powers of 2 do you want? ");

    int power[n];
    power[0] = 1;

    for (int i = 1, int j = 0; i < n; i++, j++)
    {
        printf("%i", power[j]);
        power[i] = power[i - 1] * 2;
    }
}
```

but this error comes up:

```
pw.c:11:21: error: expected identifier or '('
    for (int i = 1, int j = 0; i < n; i++, j++)
                    ^
```

I guess the problem is happenning because I'm trying to define two variables in the for loop, but I can't see why.

Comment: `int i = 1, int j = 0` is wrong. That's not how you define multiple variable of the same type. Use `int i = 1, j = 0` instead.

Comment: On a different note, you don't need an array for the problem you're solving. All you need are two variables: One for the current value, and one for the previous value.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it and now it works, I used an array because it was part of the assignment, but thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comma separated declarations in C are all of the same type and have only one type specifier:

```
for (int i = 1, j = 0; i < n; i++, j++)
```

The fact that it is in a `for` statement makes no difference - if you declared them standalone:

```
int i = 1, int j = 0 ;
```

would be invalid for the same reason and it should be:

```
int i = 1, j = 0 ;
```

To have separate types, they would need to be separate statements:

```
int i = 1; int j = 0 ;
```

which of course would not work in a `for` statement.